# css styling issue with safari and IE 8

Tags: css, asp.net, cross-browser, width

I am using a css stylesheet in one of my web pages. The styles work perfect for Mozilla and IE 7 and below. However theres a problem with it in IE8 and safari.

The width of class in the css is 700px. I have used a contentplaceholder in the master page from where this web page inherits. Now in IE8 it displays a little less than 700px. I think it displays a width of 600px. How can I solve this problem? Is there a tool for IE 8 similar to Firebug?

EDITED: I have figured exactly where the problem is by debugging the page source and the css. I dont know how I can change the width and alignment for ONLY IE8

I have fixed it for IE8 but having issues with Mac Safari. Anyway to target ONLY safari?

Thanks

Comment: Correction. When I goto IE8->Tools>Developer> and check the style for that contentplaceholder it does show me 700px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a number of changes

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8stylesheet.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

But if it's only one or two, you might just want to use embedded css

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
     <style type="text/css">
     css goes here.
     </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Either of these would go in the `<head>` section of your main page.

Comment: Works perfect now. However, I am now having the same issue with Mac Safari. Is there a way to target ONLY safari?

Comment: Conditional comments only work for IE. Personally I've never had issues with Safari so I haven't had to even consider using any CSS hacks for it. Did a bit of searching - take a look at these links, they may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838664/how-to-target-safari-for-mac-only and http://dustinbrewer.com/css-hackgetting-safari-to-behave/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
Add some different css here
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I never knew we could use if inside html. You are suggesting me to use this inside my css stylesheet or the master page or the actual aspx page? I am sorry if this question sounds silly but I have not done this before.

Comment: This would go in your .aspx page. Heres more on it They are called IE Conditional Comments http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can burn in the fiery depths of IE hell messing around with Javascript and whatnot, or you can use some (just as bad) IE hacks.

[Will targeting IE8 with conditional comments work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167657/will-targeting-ie8-with-conditional-comments-work)