# CSS default letter spacing for safari is different than other browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

I have a div with a certain width containing a text. the letter spacing is great in chrome, a bit different in Firefox and very different in Safari, So the width that I gave to my div is not sufficient for the text that is contained in it in Safari. Here is [a link to my page that is bugging](http://entendrelimage.univ-paris1.fr/?page_id=42)

I don't have any line in css that talks about letter spacing, so I am guessing this is a default property. 
Notice how the letters are overlapping at the end! How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: too bad not everyone has safari/mac :(. A screenshot could have helped.

Comment: I don't have sufficiant reputation to add images :( those rules suck !

Comment: just upload the image on imgur or something and add a link in post.

Comment: There you go Prashank :) uploaded, you can see the link in the edited section of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the difference in how the Safari on the Mac displays fonts, I think your best bet is to add browser-specific formatting.

See this question on how to add a Mac Safari class using JavaScript: [How to target Safari for Mac only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838664/how-to-target-safari-for-mac-only)

The following should be a sufficient test instead of the one from the answer in the above link:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1)
```