# horizontal submenu width constrained by upper level menu in Safari

Tags: css, menu, safari, submenu

I have a horizontal CSS menu with second-level item lists, some of which are quite lengthy. All works everywhere except Safari: it constrains the second-level menu with the width of the top-level one. Tried increasing min-width on top-level menu, doesn't work because its items are floating left. I can specify a `min-width:` combined with `margin-left:` on the top-level menu, but wondering if there is a cleaner solution.

Here is a screenshot and relevant CSS:

[image]

```
ul {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
ul > li {
    float: left;
    position: static;
}
ul > li > ul {
    display: none; /* toggled to flex on mouseover of top level menu item */
    float: left;
    left: auto;
    min-width: 32em;
    padding: 0.9em 0 0.7em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 92px;
    visibility: hidden; /* toggled to visible on mouseover of top level menu item */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tentative hack-ish option that seems to work (which I want to avoid if possible):

a) Have some JS to add a class to the `html` element in case of Safari on Mac (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838664/how-to-target-safari-for-mac-only)).

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {
    $('html').addClass('safari-mac'); // provide a class for the safari-mac specific css to filter with
}
```

b) Target the menu to have a `min-width` and a `padding-left`, which will make it longer and push it over to the right side, as per requirements.

```
.safari-mac ul {
    min-width: 50em;
    padding-left: 20em;
}
```