# Fix wrong position of dropdown with options from Select in Mac os x - chrome and safari

Tags: css, macos

I would like to know if is possible to style the dropdown with options that comes from Select.

I am looking for many days, tried some css and some jquery solutions but none work properly in osclass, in item-post.php, when we select category + subcategory.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the dropdown is misplaced, covering the actual  title. In Firefox works ok, like a usual dropdown.

The code is usual

```html
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab 95</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi TT</option>
</select>
```

So, can we force the dropdown with the options show beneath the select like in firefox or any dropdown? Thanks

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: check http://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/c32y1n9v/

Comment: You can achieve your goal only in JavaScript. I use this plugin: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: That is bad because i already tried several options and in osclass, when you post a item, the select for category and subcategory are generated from php files and they are not styled by the jquery. If you look at https://demo.osclass.org/general/index.php?page=item&action=item_add you will see that we see first a select for subcategory and when i chose a option, the second select shows. In the best case i managed to have the first select with the custom jquery style but not the second because that shows later.

Comment: use javascript to target osx platform and apply circumstanced css

Comment: Can you provide a example? I never done such thing and do not know how.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838664/how-to-target-safari-for-mac-only

Comment: Have tried a new jquery select http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/ and works great untill i make the selection from first Select. Once i do it, the second Select (with subcategories) show and that is not styled. So i assume that the jquery select is loaded already and can't be applied to this latter showing Select. So, the big question, can i add it as well for the second select when it shows? Thanks